# Cakephp is not editing enum fields value?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, enums

I am trying to edit records using cakephp,but its editing everything expect that column which's data type is enum.I tried lot but I was unable.I am giveing my code.

```
if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
  if ($this->Event->save($this->request->data)) {
  $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event has been saved'));
  } 
  else
  {
  $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
  }
}
```

My update query is showing something like below :

UPDATE `reserved`.`events` SET `performer` = 'dj', `category_id` = 8, `price_multiplier` = 1, `event_date` = '2014-03-12', `recur_week` = 'no', `id` = 1 WHERE `reserved`.`events`.`id` = '1'

Here price_multiplier column is not updating properly.
**Note :** If I can make the query like price_multiplier = '1' then my query is updating properly.I am stuck on it,any idea?

Comment: Enums are not supported. Don't use them. You can instead use approaches like [this one](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/).

Comment: @mark it shows 404 error ._.

Comment: Hadn't seen @mark 's approach before and like interesting link on the evils of ENUMs but, if you're stuck with ENUMs, this helper:http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/christian.kilb/2010/09/09/form-helper-enum-fields-to-select-boxes works fine for me (note comments in post though for CakePHP 2.x).